# how do I input a random number of items as Item ID (string) where a blank item ID signifies the last item?

Tags: c#, .net, input, c#-4.0

I want to input an unknown number of variables as Item ID which is a string and when the user enters a blank item, the program should know it is the last input.

Comment: where the user enters ItemID? in form? in file? in Console? in list?

Comment: the user inputs in the console

Comment: Create a list of string, in a loop ask the user for input, if the input isn't blank, add the value to the list, otherwise exit the loop.

Comment: Can you provide the code please, I am new to C#

Comment: I have provided some pseudocode and links to resources necessary for you to make it into real C# code.  Note that StackOverflow isn't really intended to teach you how to program. There are great tutorials, etc. for this kind of thing, and they're probably a better place to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pseudocode, but you can do it like this:

```
list = new listOf(string)
input = string.empty

do
    input = readInputFromConsole()
    if not isBlank(input) then
        list.add(input)
    end if    
while not isBlank(input)
```

Resources:

- [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0)
- [`Console.ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-6.0)
- [`string.IsNullOrEmpty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-6.0)
- [The `do` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-do-statement)
- [The `if` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-if-statement)